# how to approach moving to competitor (complicated)

Tags: colleagues

Backstory: 
I worked for a company, my boss at that company quit to go to a competitor. He called me a few weeks later and recruited me to come over. They made me an offer and I accepted. I was to work under a new boss with the new company but still work directly with my old boss. Part of the offer was that they would groom me to take on a manager position when my new boss retired in 1-2 years.

My new boss retired as expected however the industry took a downturn and they elected to merge our department with another, which resulted in my promised manager promotion being passed over. I still work directly with my old boss. The new manager is not going anywhere soon.

There are other variables at play but I am not happy at this time with my current position/manager.

Recently a third company and competitor approached me about taking on a manager role at their company, similar to the position I was promised here. It is the opportunity that I signed on for here and I am excited for the opportunity, we are just about at the point of negotiating salary etc.

The trouble I'm having trouble knowing how to approach telling my original boss about the offer and when. I still work directly with him and we have a good relationship  unfortunately I am strong in my position so he relies on me. Leaving this company will be a hit to his position as well as my department. I feel some regret that way.

What is the best way to approach this

Comment: You tell your original boss after you have a signed employment contract and have turned in your resignation.  If you got the management position you were looking for then he should understand.

Comment: So "original boss" is not your current boss, right? You two are peers at the current company? Assuming that is correct, I'd say the best way to "approach this" is by buying him a root beer. Tell him how much you appreciate what he has done for you. Then tell him about the new gig and that you have accepted (i.e., wait until you have accepted and have a start date).

Comment: @mikeazo why root beer? why not regular beer?

Comment: @alex just trying to keep everyone on their toes.

Answer (score 6):

1. Check any company handbooks or anything you've signed to see if you might be violating a contract by leaving for a competitor. Even if it is a violation, it is not commonly pursued and less commonly upheld depending on your locale.
2. Get a written offer from the other company
3. Accept other offer and provide the appropriate start date based on traditional notice periods (2 weeks is common in the U.S.)
4. Create a resignation notice and provide it to your employer
5. Since you seem to like and respect the manager, make sure you let them know before they hear it from someone else. Make sure you let them know it isn't personal and it is simply a great opportunity. Keep it positive and if the broken promise of management is brought up, simply say that was one of the things that attracted you to that position.

Comment: in which country would no1 apply  non competes are very hard to enforce

Comment: @Pepone I don't know of a list. I'm in the United States and know that different states handle non-compete differently. Some essentially won't recognize them and others might or might not. You would need to research this specifically for where you live and likely need to consult someone knowledgeable of the local laws.